# How to map bulk request response in java

Tags: java, spring, java-8

We are going to consume third party REST API service which supports bulkGETOperations , before we send the request we need to assign a unique id(bid) to each element in array and the same will be returned in response if it SUCCESS(200 OK).

Could some one please help me with the way / most efficient way to map the response based on the unique bid which was passed in the request and after mapping I need to store individual fields in database based on certain condition .Below is the sample request JSON , response will be same in below format but will contain additional fields per school

```
"testList": [
      {
        "schoolIdentifier": {
          "schoolId": "abc",
          "schoolName": {
            
            "name": "ABC"
          }
         },
        "bid": 1
        
      },
      {
        "schoolIdentifier": {
          "schoolId": "bbb",
          "schoolName": {
            
            "name": "BCD"
          }
         },
        "bid": 2
        
      }
    ]
```

Note: I am aware that this can be done with Map but looking for efficient solution using java 8

Comment: What have you tried? Did you do measure performance of different techniques? Did You start with a map or some cache ?

Comment: Hi have tried Map but am looking for java 8 streams solutions

Comment: If the request payload cannot change, consider using the following `class BulkRequest { List<SchoolBid> schoolBids;}` with `class SchoolBid { School school; int bid;}`, then on receiving the request create a `Map<Integer, School> perBidSchoolRequest` (this can be done using `groupingBy` and `mapping`). Ahead of that, you would need to iterate over the entries of this `Map`, and transform the request to its response per key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge to lookup and add the response fields. Assuming you've School class with all the request and response fields and are mapped by bid id.

```
static Map<Integer, School> merge(Map<Integer, School> request, Map<Integer, School> response) {
    Map<Integer, School> combined = new HashMap<>(request);
    response.forEach(
      (key, value) -> combined.merge(key, value, (req, resp) -> /** map additional fields from response **/ ));
    return combined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'response will be same in below format but will contain additional fields per school'
```

I suppose the response you receive already contains all you need in a School object and and you just need to convert the list response into a Map efficiently (with key as bid)

You are getting a list `testList` which contains both bid and the school Object. You can simply convert a list to the Map like :

```
 Map<Integer, SchoolDto> map = testList.parallelStream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(bidSchoolDto -> bidSchoolDto.getBid()
                    , bidSchoolDto -> bidSchoolDto.getSchool()));
```